# Is を being used at the end of the sentence to indicate emotion? 「あなた無しで生きてる私を」

Tags: grammar, particle-を

**verse**

> もし今の私を見れたなら
>
> どう思うでしょう
>
> あなた無しで生きてる私**を**

According to this [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/does-the-particle-%E3%82%92-wo-have-a-special-use-when-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) accepted answer,

> It's still the object marker. The sentence is just not finished and the verb is implied.

However, I don't think this is the case here. As far as I'm concerned, we can leave out を without changing its meaning:

> あなた無しで生きてる私 **(A)**

I've done some research online, coming across the following:

> を (Human emotion) marks a noun or noun phrase that serves as the cause of some inward human emotion. It pairs with inwardly-pointed verbs of emotion such as よろこぶ [To be glad]、[悲]{かな}しむ [To be sad]、[懐]{なつ}かしむ [To miss / To yearn for], and [悩]{なや}む [To be worried].
>
> <sup>Recovered from [wildnihongo](https://wildnihongo.com/grammar/o-human-emotion/)</sup>

No example ending with solely を was provided, though. From this source, the construction is given by **Noun / Noun Phrase + を**, which happens to be the case with **(A)**.

The source also notes that this usage of を is rather literary:

> (1) を (Human emotion) is very literary and you are unlikely to hear it in spoken Japanese.

---

This what I've gathered so far from English sources.

Comment: Related: [Still learning Japanese and I need help with this phrase "誰が止めるというの　心が叫んだ声を”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62379/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo Please correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that `あなた無しで生きてる` modifies `私` to mean `I, who lives without you`. Therefore, we could translate the verse as `If you were able to see who I am right now,
I wonder what you would think of me, who lives without you`. This is assuming that を can be placed at the end of a sentence to indicate emotion without the need of pairing it up with a verb.

Comment: In the same post a linked, there is a comment in the accepted answer saying, "Sentences ending with just を are very often interpreted in the meaning of wishing something to someone else, and I don't think anybody tries to fill in the verb for that, so perhaps you can say this specific を is quite stand-alone." This is why I think it is possible for を to be functioning as a sentence-ending particle.

Comment: It is paired with the verb 思う. It is more common to say 私のことを than 私を in normal speech or writing, though.

Comment: @Nameless You can forget that 西部に活力を question for now. In your case, the corresponding verb (思う) is right there in the second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence has the [A**を**Bと思う construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010) ("to think of A as B"), but the Bと part is replaced to どう, and どう思う is placed before the object ([倒置法](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE%E6%B3%95)). The implied subject of 思う is (seemingly deceased) あなた. 私 is modified by the relative clause あなた無しで生きてる ("who is living without you").

In the normal word order, the sentence is:

> もし(あなたが)今の私を見れたなら、
> (あなたは)あなた無しで生きてる私をどう思うでしょう

Which can be translated to:

> If you could see me as I am now,
> What would you think of me living without you?