# なんの and っていうんだ meanings

Tags: grammar, rhetorical-questions

I came across this sentence during immersion:

> それにたとえ こいつが来たからって何の役に立つっていうんだ?

What do なんの and っていうんだ mean in this case? I have read that っていうんだ is used to form a rhetorical question, while it is said also that expresses hearsay or that adds emphasis.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55644/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49111/9831

Comment: Do you understand the phrase「XXの役に立つ」?

Comment: Does it mean “what kind of help would he give” in this case?

Answer (score 1):

何の～ is "what (kind of) ～". 役に立つ is a set phrase meaning "to be useful/helpful", but this 役 is a noun ("role/function"), so it can be modified by 何の. って after 来たから is short for といって. っていうんだ forms a rhetorical question in this context. See the links in the comment.

> それに
> Besides,
>
> たとえ こいつが来たからって
> even if he came,
>
> 何の役に立つっていうんだ?
> what kind of role can he play?
> how can he be of any help?