# what does those sentences mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, conditionals, volitional-form

1:
**どうあがけば**人間が雷に勝てる**というのだ**

Here, I don't understand the どうあがけば and というのだ, what do they mean? Can someone explain to me the grammar and the usage here?

2:
空で育ったお前でも遠雷くらい**見ていよう**

What's with the 見ていよう? Why is there volition, especially in progressive form?

Comment: 見ていよう = 見ているだろう, even だろう itself is であろう

Comment: Related (regarding 1) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55644/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/49129/9831

Comment: thanks y'all but, still, i dont really understand what is the どう- ば supposed to mean exactly.

Comment: どう-ば ...というのだ (sometimes ...というのか) is a formula to mean "How on earth..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is something like:

- どうＸならばＹというのだ(か)
- What/How (much)/... on earth does one X to Y?

meaning

- Whatever/However (much)/... one does X, Y won't happen/is impossible.

More practically, X can be dropped from translation and just *How is it possible Y* would convey the meaning. Note that どうしたら="how" has essentially the same structure (literally *how does one do to..*).

Explanation by examples:

> どうあがけば人間が雷に勝てるというのだ 
> How much must one struggle to defeat thunder? 
> How on earth can one defeat thunder?

> どう見たらこれが猫だと思うのだ 
> What do you see to think that this is a cat? 
> How come you think this is a cat?

---

I think your confusion stems from the fact that there is no construction in English which naturally combines *how* and *if*, which is what どう・・ば does.

I'm not sure how much this helps, but see the following comparisons.

- こうすれば人間は雷に勝てる

which literally translates to

- If one does this, one can beat thunder.

Now changing こう to どう and adding というのだ, it becomes (literally)

- If one does **how/what**, can one beat thunder?

Slightly more naturally,

- Can one beat thunder by doing *what*?

In the case of the sentence in question, a similar translation is

- Can one beat thunder by struggling how?